# Target submission vs target release date

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I'm currently filling the form to get a chance to be featured on the App Store by telling them "my story" but I have absolutely no idea what's the difference between `Target Submission Date` and `Target Release Date`. What should I do?

[image]